# How can I get this code to run properly? I'm having issues with the if and else statements and apparently it's not indented correctly

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation

I'm trying to create a program that calculates the stopping distance of a car and I want to make it so that if the user inputs the deceleration as greater than 0, then the program will print `Cannot use positive integers`. Also, the program is having indention errors with the `else` statements.

I already played around with the indentation and it doesn't fix anything.

```
a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
if a > 0:
        print "cannot be a positive integer"

else a < 0: 
    s1 = (0 - float(u)**2)
    s2 = (2*float(a))
    s = s1/s2
 print "The vehicle will travel %s meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s)
```

Comment: What data type does `raw_input` return?

Comment: it returns string, so you should cast the input to integer or float by using, int(a) or float(a), e.g. if int(a)>0:

Comment: you can check the type of any variable by using the function type(), so if you write  print(type(a)) will tell you that it is 'str' which is short for string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is indeed incorrectly indented. Your last print function should be backspaced once to be out of *else*. Secondly, else does not receive a condition, *i.e*, if you type:

```
   if a > 5: 
    print(True) 
   else a < 5: 
    print(False)
```

You will receive the following message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Two options to solve it:

```
   if a > 5: 
    print(True) 
   else: 
    print(False)
```

or

```
   if a > 5: 
    print(True) 
   elif a < 5: 
    print(False)
```

Third, as your object **a** is a string, the first condition *a > 0* will fail, once that to accomplish such comparison **a** must be an *int* or *float*;

Lastly, raw_input is not a valid function in Python 3.x. If you go to a more recent version of Python, you should substitute it for just *input ()*. With that in mind, your code should look something like this:

```
a = input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
a = int(a)
if a > 0:
    print ("cannot be a positive integer")

else: 
    s1 = (0 - float(u)**2)
    s2 = (2*float(a))
    s = s1/s2
print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters per second before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If they're in Python 3, then `print x` rather than `print(x)` is also going to be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good start for solving the problems with your code. The correct indentation is the following:

```
a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
if a > 0:
    print("cannot be a positive integer")
elif a < 0: 
    s1 = (0 - float(u)**2)
    s2 = (2*float(a))
    s = s1/s2
    print("The vehicle will travel %s meters per second before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
```

Notice I added the parentheses to the `print()` module. Also, I traded out your `else` with `elif`, since another `if` is what is required if you want to condition it.

Here's some other hints to consider:
1) Try copying and pasting the error message with your post. You'll find that learning to read the errors will benefit you greatly. Feel free to comment them to this answer for further guidance. 
2) If you are using python 3.*, `raw_input()` is depreciated. freecodecamp.com has a great montra: "Read-Search-Ask" in that order.
3) `raw_input()`, or at least the python3 version I used, will give you a char return.

Good luck!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Where are you getting that it's Python 2?

Comment: @Acccumulation He's the OP and he never said it was python2. Wierd response, bc I was just being helpful. The root of the problem is that he's making a lot of mistakes and he came here for beginner tutoring. I thought I was obliging him, in spite of the culture of this site that would sooner shoo him away for asking without trying every obvious alternative first.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, pythonstudent23 is the OP, and MarcinOrlowshi just edited it.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I fixed more than just his parentheses. I also said "If you are using python 3.*" I went through it and I solved the whole thing for myself and fixed it, but seeing as how he needs to do a lot more troubleshooting than just indentation, I'm waiting to reveal more if he needs it. 

What's more, I just tested my code with no import and using `print()` with parentheses on python 2.7.15. Still works like a charm. I can show it to you when the OP is done with this troubleshooting lesson.